# Examples of free noncommutative Banach algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

In abstract algebra, we have the notion of *[free algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra)*. But does the concept of *free Banach algebras* also make sense?

> Suppose $\mathcal{A}:=k\langle X_1, \cdots, X_n \rangle$, where $n>1$, is a finitely generated (noncommutative) *free* $k$-algebra, where $k$ is the field of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose a norm $\|\cdot\|$ makes $\mathcal{A}$ a normed algebra such that $\|a\cdot_\mathcal{A} b\|\leq \|a\|\|b\|$, for all $a,b\in \mathcal{A}$. **Then, is the completion $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ w.r.t this norm a *free* Banach algebra?**
> The noncommutative multiplication in $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ is defined as the natural extension of the multiplications in $\mathcal{A}$: For $a'=\lim a_n$ and $b'=\lim b_n$ in $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$, where $(a_n), (b_n)\subset \mathcal{A}$,
> $$a' \cdot_{\hat{\mathcal{A}}} b':=\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n\cdot_\mathcal{A} b_n). $$

If the above construction does make sense, are there well-known concrete examples of (noncommutative) *free* Banach algebras out there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just take polynomial functions on $[0,1]$ with $\|\ast\|_\infty$ as a norm, then $A \simeq \mathbb{R} [X]$, and $\hat{A} = C^0 ([0,1])$. The only issue here (and always) is that you won't find a finitely generated algebra. Probably use Baire to show it.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem with this example is that this is a free *abelian* algebra. I'm more thinking of the noncommutative case in general.

Comment: a free abelian is also free; I answered you question Do you have an example of free non abelian algebra of finite type which completion is not the original algebra in itself? These are very complicated objects. Maybe look for the completed path algebra of a quiver, but its topology is non metric...

Comment: Maybe edit your post and change the $X_n$ for $a_n$ since they are used for commutative polynomial algebras

Comment: Thanks. Just updated.